# Prevent ember-data from reloading relations from server if they are specified as links

Tags: javascript, ajax, caching, ember.js, ember-data

I'm using `Ember-CLI 0.2.7` with `Ember-Data v1.0.0-beta.19.2` and `Ember 1.13.0`. I'm facing the following problem:

I have tags which have many items. So there is a `hasMany` relation from tags to items. An item can also belong to many tags to there is also a `hasMany` relation into the other direction.

Therefore the file models/tag.js looks as follows:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
    //...
    // Relationships
    items: DS.hasMany('item', {async: true}),
    //...
});
```

and models/item.js

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
    //...
    // Relationships
    tags: DS.hasMany('tag', {async: true}),
    //...
});
```

When I request all tags from the server, the server responses with

```
{
    "meta": {
        "total": 162
    },
    "tags": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            // ...
            "links": {
                "items": "/tags/1/items"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Now if I'm doing somewhere `var items = tag.get('items')` Ember-Data correctly fetches the items belonging to the tag with an ajax call. But depending from where the user enters a certain page it could be possible that all items are already in the store. So a ajax call is unnecessary. Is there a way to tell Ember-data that the items are already in the store and that it can lookup all items to the tag in the store?

The use case where a subsequent ajax call is annoying for me is a simple version of `infinite scroll`. Fetching all the items again from the server is not good for the UX because it makes scrolling stuttering. The best thing in my opinion would be to preload all items with a single ajax call and then resolve the relations to the tag with the items in memory.

Is there any chance to achieve this behavior? Some reopen, extend, overwrite etc?

Answer (score 0):

With `links` there is no way to achieve: if all `items` already are in the `store` or not.

You could use `ids` instead of `links`:

```
{
  "tags": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        // ...
        "items": [1, 2, 3],
    }
  ]
}
// or "item_ids" in case of ActiveModelAdapter
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. So I know, that I don't need to waste time in searching some solution. My idea was something like a "own" adapter which is aware of how the links are build. My concern about the `ids` solution is, that I don't want to make 1000 requests to get the items (if I need them somewhere else on the page, were not all items are already loaded). I know there exists a coalesce option. But would this work for 1000 ids?

Comment: You are right, "ids" are good for small amounts only, it is disadvantage. As for me, there are **no "one size fits all" solution** for associations. I think, the right choice is depended of your user interface. For example, click on stack-overflow "ember" tag. You'll see only first 15 questions and then pagination works. For such UI only `tag.firstFifteenItems` relation needed (my opinion). So you have to find what suits your UI.